# how to upload audio file to server

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to know if there is a way to upload files server-side
mainly I want to upload audios in a specific folder
I first tried to upload and download by js but it didn't work
here is HTML

```
    <body>
        
        <!-- <button type="button" class="btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"> -->
            <img src="assets/upload-btn.png" alt="" type="button" class="btn-img" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
          <!-- </button> -->
        
          <!-- The Modal -->
          <div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
              <div class="modal-content">
              
                <!-- Modal Header -->
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <h4 class="modal-title">Upload Audio</h4>
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                </div>
                
                <!-- Modal body -->
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form action="save?">
                        <input type="file" name="Audio" id="upload-aud" accept="Audio/mp3">
                    </form>
                </div>
                
                <!-- Modal footer -->
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <input class="btn-submit "type="submit" id="submit" value="Upload" data-dismiss="modal" onclick=save()> 
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </span>
    </body>
```

Comment: Please define [it didn't work](https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/). What exactly isn't working? What have you tried to solve this problem? This seems to be a server-side issue, but you sisn't include any server-side code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all, to upload a media file (image, video, audio) to server, you need a backend. meaning you need to write some backend code with languages like PHP or Nodejs or Python... .

in the client side, you need to send the file to backend. this can be done two ways.

one, use a simple form :

```
<form action="save.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <input type="file" name="Audio" id="upload-aud" accept="Audio/mp3">
    <input type="submit" value="save file">
</form>
```

this form will send a media file with the name "Audio" to the save.php file which is your backend.

second method is to use javascript and fetch the file from the input and send an ajax request. you can get the file from the input like this:

```
var file = document.getElementById('upload-aud').files[0]
```

now, the `file`  variable contains your media file and you can use ajax to send it.